# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find' with python 2.7 using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-2.7

I just began python crawling and have tried to crawl web text for a month. 
I tried this code with python 2.7.13 and it worked well before.

```
class IEEECrawler:
    def __init__(self):
        self.baseUrl = "http://ieeexplore.ieee.org"
        self.targetUrl = "http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/mostRecentIssue.jsp?reload=true&filter%3DAND%28p_IS_Number%3A4359286%29&rowsPerPage=100&pageNumber=1&resultAction=REFINE&resultAction=ROWS_PER_PAGE&isnumber=4359286#1.html"
        self.soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.urlopen(self.targetUrl).read(), "lxml")
        self.doc_list = self.soup.find_all('div', {'class': "txt"})
        self.subUrl = []

    def crawlOriginalPage(self):
        file = open("./result.txt", "w")
        for doc in self.doc_list:
            head = doc.find("h3")
            author_list = ''
            for author in doc.find_all("div", {'class':"authors"}):
                for tt in author.find_all('span', {'id':"preferredName"}):
                    author_list += tt['data-author-name'] + ";"
            author_list = author_list[:-1]
            file.write(head.find("span").text + ';')
            file.write(author_list.strip() + ';')
            file.write(self.baseUrl+head.find('a')['href']+ ';')
            file.write(doc.find("div", {'class': "hide abstract RevealContent"}).find("p").text.replace('View full abstract'+'»'.decode('utf-8'),'').strip()+ '\n')
        file.close()
        print 'finish'
```

However, today I ran this code again, I doesn't work with this error masseges. I can't figure out what code should be fixed.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/Downloads/ieee_fin/ieee.py", line 35, in <module>
    crawler.crawlOriginalPage()
  File "/Users/user/Downloads/ieee_fin/ieee.py", line 29, in crawlOriginalPage
    file.write(doc.find("div", {'class': "hide abstract RevealContent"}).find("p").text.replace('View full abstract'+'»'.decode('utf-8'),'').strip()+ '\n')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

Comment: `doc` is null. Debug to find out why.

Answer (score 0):

The error shows you the line:

```
file.write(doc.find("div", {'class': "hide abstract RevealContent"}).find("p").text.replace('View full abstract'+'»'.decode('utf-8'),'').strip()+ '\n')
```

Just look for the method `find` (there are 2) and check to see what comes before it.

Maybe this is bad:

```
doc.find(...)
```

Which would mean that `doc` was type NoneType, which would mean that `doc` was `None`.

Or maybe this is bad:

```
doc.find("div", {'class': "hide abstract RevealContent"}).find("p")
```

Which would mean that `doc.find(...class...)` is returning `None`. Possibly because it couldn't find any.

Bottom line, you probably either need to put a `try...except` wrapper around that code, or break it up a little and start checking for `None`.

Comment: Thank you, Austin. Your comment is really helpful. I will try and post about it later.